# How to make outer div has the same submit behavior as its content asp.net button

Tags: asp.net, html, input, submit

I have a div with rounded corners in asp.net form, it contains a "submit" which is written in asp.net button.

The four corners are not clickable and don't have the same behavior as "submit" button.

How can i do to make the whole div clickable and have the same behavior as clicking the button?

Any ideas are welcome.

```
<div>
<a>
<span>
<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions....etc" value="Valider" name="">
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Because I can't get the same behavior out of the asp.net button, I've deleted wrapper "a ,span" and used asp:ImageButton. It works now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this function - based on `click JQuery method` (defined on your div)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".summary").click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).find("input").eq(0).attr('href');
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Nota : define href on your input

Add to your code summary class

```
<div class="summary">
<a>
<span>
<input type="submit" value="Valider" name="">
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reasons, javascript is not allowed in code, but thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simly look at what is in the submit button's onclick event and just assign the same to the div click event using jquery or in the html?

something like:

`$("#myDiv").click(WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions....etc);`

or

`<div id="myDiv" onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions....etc' />`

you will also have to add `cursor:pointer` to the div's style to indicate it's clickable